# MATLAB GUI: Slider as scrollbar; subpanel doesn't clip

Tags: matlab, user-interface, slider, scrollbar, clipping

Long time lurker -- I really appreciate the community's knowledge. I've seen this question posed a couple of times here and elsewhere, though I've yet to find a suitable solution. If I missed a previously-listed answer, please post the link and accept my apologies.

My GUI figure has a main panel with a uibuttongroup as tabs at the top. Each tab enables visibility of different over-sized subpanels (filled with various content), and I use a slider to scroll the subpanels up & down.

Generally, this works. However, when I scroll down, the content of the subpanels (not the subpanels themselves) covers my tabs at the top (which should always be visible). I thought that it may have something to do with clipping, but I can't figure out how to make that work. Does anybody know how to prevent this from happening?

I have included code (with limited functionality for brevity) that shows my situation:

```
function h = ScrollQuestion_StackOverflow


h.myFig = figure('position', [100 100 800 600],...
    'menubar','none');


%% Panel covers full figure
h.Main_Panel = uipanel('Parent', h.myFig,...
    'units','normalized',...
    'position', [0 0 1 1],...
    'visible','on');


%% ALWAYS needs to be visible by the user, not covered by anything
h.Main_BtnGrp = uibuttongroup('parent', h.Main_Panel,...
    'units','normalized',...
    'position', [0 .95 1 .05]);

h.Tab1_TglBtn = uicontrol('parent', h.Main_BtnGrp,...
    'units','normalized',...
    'position', [0 0 .125 1],...
    'style','togglebutton',...
    'string', 'Tab1');

h.Tab2_TglBtn = uicontrol('parent', h.Main_BtnGrp,...
    'units','normalized',...
    'position', [.125 0 .125 1],...
    'style','togglebutton',...
    'string', 'Tab2');


%% Oversized sub-panel
h.ThisPanelMoves = uipanel('parent',h.Main_Panel,...
    'units','normalized',...
    'position', [0 -1 1 1.95]);

% Generic content of sub-panel
h.ContentText = uicontrol('parent', h.ThisPanelMoves,...
    'units','normalized',...
    'position', [.05 .95 .8 .05],...
    'style','text',...
    'string', 'BLOCKS TABS WHEN YOU SCROLL DOWN',...
    'fontsize', 20,...
    'clipping','on');


%% Add slider
h.Tab1_Slider = uicontrol('Parent', h.myFig,...
    'units','normalized',...
    'position',[.98, 0 .02 1],...
    'style', 'slider',...
    'value', 1,...
    'callback', {@SliderCallback, h});

guidata(h.myFig,h)


%% Slider Callback
function SliderCallback(hObject, eventdata, h)
    val = get(hObject,'Value');
    set(h.ThisPanelMoves, 'Position', [0 -val 1 1.95]);
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Though I'm not entirely satisfied, I found a workaround: It seems that the order of creation determines which item is on top. If I create the oversized sub-panel first and the uibuttongroup second, then the tabs are on top when I scroll down. The visual is still not super pretty, but it seems to work.

Comment: If someone (1) knows how to clean up the visual [I'd rather the subpanel content not show through the uibuttongroup frame] or (2) knows how to 'bring an item to the front' regardless of creation order, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

[`uistack()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uistack.html) will allow you to adjust the order of your uicontrol objects. It doesn't seem like children inherit the position of their parent so you can't just move your panel to the top and call it a day. Calling it for each of the tab toggles gives the desired result.

```
uistack(h.Tab1_TglBtn,'top');
uistack(h.Tab2_TglBtn,'top');
```

It still passes over the panel borders, so you'll have to adjust your other objects as necessary to get a more aesthetically pleasing GUI.

I'm not 100% sure what properties `uistack` is modifying to adjust the object order, the code is present if you do an `open uistack`, but I haven't had a chance to look through it to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your function:

```
function SliderCallback(hObject, eventdata, h)
    val = get(hObject,'Value');
    set(h.ThisPanelMoves, 'Position', [0 -val 1 1.95]);
end
```

For this:

```
function SliderCallback(hObject, eventdata, h)
    val = get(hObject,'Value');
    set(h.ThisPanelMoves, 'Position', [0 -val 1 0.95]);
end
```

In your code, height of the moving panel is greater than the window size (1.95, while the limit of the window is 1).

And set max and min limits to '1' and '0' in the slider in order to not to have circular movement:

```
%% Add slider h.Tab1_Slider = uicontrol('Parent', h.myFig,...
    'units','normalized',...
    'position',[.98, 0 .02 1],...
    'style', 'slider',...
    'value', 1, 'max', 1, 'min', 0,...
    'callback', {@SliderCallback, h});
```